# Местоимение-заместитель в отсутствие замещаемого слова

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, местоимения

*Опишите **каждое решение** и предложите выбрать одно **из них**.*

В предложении перед местоимением "них" формально нет замещаемого им существительного множественного числа. Допустимо ли использовать это местоимение, если по смыслу фразы понятно, что оно указывает на решения, которые будут описаны? Другими словами, может ли местоимение представлять не только явно упомянутое существительное, но и подразумеваемое?

**Дополнение**

Заметил, что такое употребление местоимения (без явно упомянутого существительного, которое оно замещает) часто встречается после определительных местоимений "каждый" и "любой". По видимому, они в себе содержат информацию о том, что существует множество предметов/явлений, на которые затем местоимение "них" и ссылается.

*Наркотики, по сути своей, — это яды. Их действие определяется принятым количеством. Маленькая доза стимулирует. Бо́льшая доза действует как седативное средство. Ещё бо́льшая доза действует как яд и может убить человека. Это справедливо для **любого наркотика**. Но для каждого **из них** эти дозы будут различными*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Наркотики, по сути своей, — это яды. Их действие определяется принятым количеством. Маленькая доза стимулирует. Бо́льшая доза действует как седативное средство. Ещё бо́льшая доза действует как яд и может убить человека. Это справедливо для любого наркотика. Но для каждого из них эти дозы будут различными.*

В этом тексте сочетается **параллельная и последовательная** связь предложений.

**Параллельная** часть текста связана с одной темой: *Наркотики, по сути своей, — это яды. Их действие (наркотиков) определяется принятым количеством. Это справедливо для любого наркотика. Но для каждого из них (из наркотиков) эти дозы будут различными.*

Во всех предложениях речь идет **о наркотиках**. Местоимение заменяет существительное, чтобы не было повтора этого слова, и ссылается  на ключевое слово **для данной части текста**, даже если они не расположены рядом. В тоже время по построению текста **должно быть понятным**,  какое слово оно замещает.

В каждом случае надо  учитывать **конкуренцию со стороны ближайших существительных,** а также устный или письменный вариант речи. (В письменном варианте в зоне внимания находятся несколько ближайших предложений).

Речь  в данной части текста идет о наркотиках, причем **это слово постоянно повторяется.** Значит, в последнем предложении местоимение с большой вероятностью относится именно к наркотикам, которые, кстати, **названы   и в предыдущем** предложении.

**Но конкуренция всё-таки есть,** это существительное ***человек,*** которое подходит и по форме, и по смыслу: **своя доза  для каждого человека или для каждого наркотика?** Если это неясно, то можно говорить о стилистической погрешности текста.

Однако в данном случае местоимение относится именно к наркотикам, которые только что были упомянуты. Возможно, для этого два последних предложения, тесно связанных по смыслу, **не объединяются** в одно сложное.

**Розенталь о правильности употребления местоимений**

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm

1. Местоимение 3-го лица (он, она, оно, они) **обычно заменяет ближайшее к нему предшествующее существительное в форме того же рода и числа.** Однако эта связь местоимения с существительным определяется **иногда смыслом, а не формально порядком слов,** например: Туристы побывали во многих городах страны: они интересовались прежде всего местными историческими достопримечательностями (**не вызывает сомнений**, что местоимение они относится к более отдаленному существительному туристы, а не к ближе стоящему городах).

Возможность соотнесения местоимения **с разными словами в предшествующем тексте** может служить источником **неясности или двусмысленности**, например: Сестра поступила в артистическую труппу, она скоро уезжает на гастроли (кто уезжает – сестра или труппа?). В этих случаях необходима правка; ср.:

а) Сестра поступила в артистическую труппу и скоро уезжает на гастроли;

б) Сестра поступила в артистическую труппу, которая скоро уезжает на гастроли;

Comment: Прочитал наш отрывок снова. «Наркотики», о которых говорится в первых двух предложениях, не держатся в памяти до того места, где употреблено местоимение «них». В памяти держится максимум предыдущее предложение. Так что привязка местоимения к "ключевому слову в данной части текста" мне кажется сомнительной — именно с практической, читательской точки зрения.

Comment: Когда читатель видит местоимение *них*, в своей памяти он прежде всего натыкается на существительное *наркотика* в предыдущем предложении.

Comment: Текст частично исправлен с учетом замечаний.

Comment: Спасибо большое за дополнение ответа. Только существительное *человек* же единственного числа — почему же оно "подходит по форме", если местоимение *них* множественного числа и в предшествующем тексте нет слова *люди*?

Comment: Текст о наркотиках в качестве примера выбран неудачно. Вот что я на самом деле хочу узнать в своём вопросе: если в предшествующем тексте есть **только** существительное в единственном числе, может ли местоимение *них* в сочетании *каждый/любой из них* относиться к подразумеваемому существительного множественного числа (*наркотики*, *люди*)?

Comment: Согласование бывает по смыслу и по форме. В данном случае выбрано согласование по смыслу. Если описывают каждое решение, то понятно, что их несколько . Каждый - это один из ряда подобных.

Answer (score 2):

Допустимо. На мой любительский взгляд, когда вы говорите "Опишите каждое решение", то тоже подразумеваете "из них". Вся фраза построена на том, что читателю известны "они" — некие решения. Формально говоря, я где-то встречал фразу, что местоимение может представлять не только явно упомянутое существительное, но и подразумеваемое.